# How do I know the password for my encrypted home directory?

Tags: command-line, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encrypted Home… Forgotten Password, but no Passphrase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120206/encrypted-home-forgotten-password-but-no-passphrase)

I encrypted my Home to protect against hackers of course when I first installed Ubuntu. It loaded up the Terminal and was attempting to show me my encryption password incase it ever needed to be used. So I thought "Ehh what the heck, I can find it out later..."

So I closed Terminal and went on with the (amazing!) Ubuntu life. But now I am having to install Java JDK 7.0.0.4 onto my computer to ya know, play games and such. But it is asking for my password for the encrypted Home folder but it never gave it to me... HELP!!!

Does anyone remember the command for Terminal to give you you're randomly generated Encryption password pop up on the famous purple window?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't an encryption issue, installing software requires your admin user password.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you are trying to install java, which (I presume it wants root access) needs an administrator's *logon* password, not the encryption key. Just give it the password you use to log on to Ubuntu. In fact, it is using `sudo`(or some GUI spinoff, like `kdesudo`, or `gksudo`) which uses the admin logon password to get rights to do anything under the system under the root account.

Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Edit: Also, if it actually needs the encryption key, feel free to run:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
```

upon the terminal to get the long hex string you need.

Comment: I have attempted to enter my login password but it does not type it out. The "cursor" just flashes waiting for an input on the keyboard, and when I entered the command you gave me (for the encrypted password) it just said ecryptfs-recover-passphrase: command not found

Comment: @CarlosL. The logon password will ***NOT*** be shown., Still type it and press enter. Also, see edits to answer for the correct command(apologies for error at first).

Comment: Ok sorry if I am starting to anger you... I ran the unwrap passphrase command WITH the arguments, but it gave me a Error: Unwrapping passphrase failed [-5]

Comment: @CarlosL. no, you are not angering me at all, I just have 5 hours to kill, but _try it without the arguments_, or ensure you have the correct password when the command prompts you. Also, does installing Java work? The logon password isn't shown at all(not even asterisks) by design.

Comment: Ok well the no arguments did not work either... And do you want me to link you to the website that I am using as a guide to install Java from?

Comment: @CarlosL. sorry for slow reply, but the link would really help. Just try typing your logon password at the prompt, although you can't see it.