# Can't decrypt files - passphrase doesn't work

Tags: password, encryption, ecryptfs

I have the exact same problem as this gentleman had here: [Encrypted Home... Forgotten Password, but no Passphrase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120206/encrypted-home-forgotten-password-but-no-passphrase)
, i had an old user with with encrypted /home folder and changed the password from another user to be able to login again. I still have the encryption key stored but the password doesn't work (tried the old and the new one).

What can i do now? I can only MOUNT the encrypted partition but the files are still encrypted and i can't view them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To all those with the same problem, i managed to fix my problem by changing my password again to the original one i had. After that even without a LOGIN passphrase i was able to read the files with the MOUNT passphrase only using the ecryptfs-recover-private procedure.