# Decrypt home folder without passphrase

Tags: passphrase

I just reinstalled Ubuntu after my system crashed. I installed it on another hard drive (separate from my previous one).

However, my old home folder from my previous system was encrypted and I do not have the passphrase to decrypt my home folder. Is it still possible to recover the data?

Comment: like sameetandpotatoes said below there is no way to recover the data without a passphrase by design. My suggestion would be write down every passphrase you have ever used or are likely to use and see if you can't luck out and end up hacking your own home folder. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120206/encrypted-home-forgotten-password-but-no-passphrase). As stated by the accepted answer:

> If you do not have either of these pieces of information [the old login password or the mount passphrase used], then the information is lost. This is by design, since if you could access the data under these circumstances then so could an attacker.

I'm sorry but I do not think you will be able to recover the data.