# I can only login as guest

Tags: login, password

I did a password change, but it wasn't memorable enough, so I had to reset my password using a series of commands from the root shell in recovery mode:

```
# mount -rw -o remount /
# passwd {username}
Enter new password:
Successfully changed.
# exit
```

I then restarted my computer and entered my password. It acted like it was going to log on but brought me back to the login page.

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and logged in successfully.  `dir` and `ls` yield two files: `README.txt`, and something along the lines of `desktop-private-files-and-folders.dir`. I cannot `cd` to any directory.

I tried to use the Live CD but in the test profile when I try to access the information on my mounted hard drive it tells me that I do not have permission to access it, nor can I copy that information.

I have tried to be as thorough and detailed as possible without adding any fluff.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you set up an encrypted home directory for your user account.

You have probably broken the decryption of the ecryptfs mount passphrase and will need to use ecryptfs-recover-private to recover it - see the instructions in this answer to a related question [Encrypted Home... Forgotten Password, but no Passphrase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120206/encrypted-home-forgotten-password-but-no-passphrase)