# Problem login in

Tags: login, password

This might sound noobish,
but, I wanted to change my username and password of my computer(ubuntu 12.4 I think)
I changed the password, and it worked, I changed the username - and it worked, so I logged out and tried to log back in, but every time I enter the new password, the computer goes to a black screen for a sec, then goes back to the log-in page,

the only way I can login is by going in with guest.
and I can't delete anything because I don't have permission

after doing

```
mount -o remount,rw /
cd /home
ls -al
```

this is the output:

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 mar 18 09:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 mar 18 09:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mar 18 09:03 .ecryptfs
dr-x------ 3 itay itay 4096 mar 18 09:09 itay
```

so i did this:
mount -o remount,rw /
cd /home
chmod u+w itay

mount -o remount,rw /
cd /home/itay
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.backup

now it logged in to my user, but i can login in terminal, what can i do?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/336875/241580) question might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem sounds very similar to me.

Go to recovery-root-shell, type in:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
cd /home
ls -al
```

Pls post your output here, maybe you have the same problem :)

Edit 1:
This sounds good, you can try following commands in the recovery shell:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
cd /home
chmod u+w itay
```

When this command don't solve your problem you can try STRG + ALT + F1 at the graphical login and try to log in in the commandline.
When the login in the commandline works you can try the following commands (recovery):

```
mount -o remount,rw /
cd /home/itay
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.backup
```

And now try again to log in :)

If this don't help, I think saiarcot895 give you already the right answer.

Comment: First of all ty for answering so quickly,
secondly, here is the output:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 mar 18 09:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 mar 18 09:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mar 18 09:03 .ecryptfs
dr-x------ 3 itay itay 4096 mar 18 09:09 itay

.ecryptfs and the last itay is written with blue, and itay is my username/name for the computer

Comment: Ok, I think it worked. but now I cant login in terminal.... what can I do about that?