# How can I recover the password of an encrypted Home folder?

Tags: password, encryption, password-recovery

I forgot my encryption password and now can't access my laptop. I have tried using the command line to remove it, and the bootloader. The home folder is blocked by the encryption code.

Is there a way to recover my password, or otherwise decrypt the home folder?

Comment: I don't know it 100% sure, but I think not. If it were easy to remove the encryption without the password, it wouldn't much useful.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120206/encrypted-home-forgotten-password-but-no-passphrase

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that you can easily recover the encryption code and access your data. Unless you're a security expert, or have access to some brilliant minds from the NSA, you must recover your password to be able to access your data. That's in a gist the trouble with securely stored data: if you lose your key, no one can access it anymore. Not easily, anyways...

You may of course attempt brute-force methods to try to decrypt your device, given that you must have an idea about its characteristics (length, symbols or numbers used, etc.), and perhaps you already know it partially. Unfortunately I wouldn't have any precise recommendations to give here. Try to check out http://security.stackexchange.com for possible solutions.