# How to deal with forgotten password without loosing any data from ubuntu based laptop?

Tags: 14.04, password, kde

When I logged in today on my laptop and tried to do something  it asked me for my password. So i typed in my password  and it keeps on saying that It's invalid.  I know for sure I didn't change it. Is there any way to change it or make it work without loosing any data from my laptop ? How do I reset a lost  password? doesn't work for me. 
please any one suggest how to make it work without loosing any data because if any data are remove my research work are totally stop .

Comment: Stupid question but: Have you checked Num Lock, Caps Lock etc., Keyboard language settings? Moreover, is your home partition encrypted or not. If yes, better remember that password....

Comment: Just in case, you do have an encryptfs encrypted home, read the answer to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/120206/encrypted-home-forgotten-password-but-no-passphrase question

Answer (score 0):

Boot your machine into Recovery mode and choose root like explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), then  remount your hardisk to read/write access then you can use `passwd` to set a new password for your user. Just be aware not to change the root password in this console. Also look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) for more about this problem.