# Forgot ecryptfs password and know just my current user password and my screen is broken. Can't login

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs

First thing, my laptop screen is broken so I used to use it by connecting it to a TV with an HDMI cable.

I tried to log in after a long time, and I seem to have forgotten the ecryptfs password. I just know my current user password. Also as my screen is broken, on TV I can't see the tty so I have to blindly type in the user password and commands.

Firstly, is there a way to mount the home directory, knowing just my current user login and not even the root password.

Secondly, is there some script that I can just type in to remove the encyption as I can't view the outputs from the commands run from the tty.

Comment: The whole point of encrypting data is to make sure nobody can decrypt them without knowing the passphrase.

Comment: This is a tough situation. Maybe you remember after a good night's sleep. But if the Ubuntu system is still working, it should work to login via a text screen, and it would make the encrypted home available. It might work to move the hard disk drive to another computer and boot it there, at least to get a text screen or simple graphics with the boot option `nomodeset`.

Comment: I don't know your setup, but shouldn't ecryptfs use a random password that it generated itself and stored on the disk, encrypted with your user password? That way you should only have to enter your user password to decrypt that directory - unless you change your user password. See: http://askubuntu.com/q/120206/367990 - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory - http://askubuntu.com/q/36573/367990 - http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/ - http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html